# Shell script for append string to first of each row in column 6 of csv file

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I have 100 csv files with 10 columns and 1000 rows . In column 6, I have a number and I want to append `93` at first of it.

for example :

Source :

```
2014-06-20 00:05:44,2014-06-2000:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,**788950270**,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
```

Result :

```
2014-06-20 00:05:44,2014-06-2000:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,**93788950270**,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be accomplished using the bash `read -a` command to loop through the data files, reading 10 values from a csv file, prepending '93' to the sixth element (array element 5 on a 0 based array), and then writing the values back out to a tmp file until done and then replacing the original (after backup) with the tmp file. **NOTE** depending on whether the original files have a trailing new line at the end, you may need to add/remove the newline that will be present at the end of the reformat operation.

**NOTE:** this is only valid for `10` csv values per line (any number of rows)

```
#!/bin/bash

test -r "$1" || { printf "error invalid file: $1\n"; exit 1; }

tmpfile=./tmp.txt
declare -a array

IFS=$','
:>$tmpfile

while read -a array || test -n "${array[9]}"; do
    array[5]="93${array[5]}"
    for ((i=0; i<9; i++)); do
        printf "${array[i]}," >> $tmpfile
    done
    printf "${array[9]}\n" >> $tmpfile
done <"$1"

cp -a "$1" "${1}.bak"
cp -a $tmpfile "$1"
rm $tmpfile

exit 0
```

input (taken from your example and date changed on each record to make unique):

```
2014-03-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
2014-04-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
2014-05-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
2014-06-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
```

output

```
2014-03-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,93788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
2014-04-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,93788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
2014-05-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,93788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
2014-06-20 00:05:44,2014-06-20 00:08:46,x.x.x.x,091xxxx,x.x.x.x,93788950270,,971xxx,479xxxx,9xxx
```

Again **NOTE** this is a non-trivial operation if your files are production files, so backup before, the script will also make a backup of the data file, and then verify the presence/absence of the trailing newline in the original.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{$6=substr($6,3);$6="**"93$6}1' FILENAME
```

if field `#6` have not `**` use this:

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{$6=93$6}1' FILENAME
```

Comment: doesn't that add \*\* before the 93? like: \*\*938950270, would awk -F, -vOFS="," '{$6=substr($6,3);$6=""93$6}1' be better?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : no, `substr` deleted `**` from field `6` , and we should add this again to first

Comment: I really like your solution, I knew awk was the swiss-army knife of text files.